# unable to add photo from iphone to canvas

Tags: javascript, ios, html, canvas, fabricjs

hopefully this is just my error but i have this working on PC/android devices.
When loaded on iOS it doesnt draw images from device to canvas (safari and chrome tested)
The chosen image thumbnail is visible next to the file input.

**Fabric Version**: 1.5.0

**Test Case**: https://jsfiddle.net/v8jrpnu2/18/

```
window.addEventListener('load', function onLoad() {
  photo = new fabric.Canvas('photo')
  photo.setWidth(600);
  photo.setHeight(600);
  photo.backgroundColor = '#eee';
  photo.renderAll();

  var upload = function(e) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];

      reader.onload = function(e){

        contents = e.target.result;
        var image = new Image();

        image.src = contents;

        var Cimage = new fabric.Image(image);
        photo.add(Cimage);

        photo.renderAll();
      }
      if(file) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
    }

  $('#upload-input').on('change', function(e){
    upload(e);
  });
});
```

**Steps to reproduce**

load fiddle on iPhone (tested on iphone 5 and 5C)
use file input to select image

**Expected Behavior**

image renders on canvas

**Actual Behavior**

image does not render on canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle didn't worked on my desktop FF either...

The main fix is to wrap your `fabric.Image(image)` inside the `image.onload` event handler, otherwise, the image is still empty when Fabric tries to convert it in one of its Image Object.

Aside fixes consist in passing directly the `upload` handler to the event listener, and to use `this.files[0]` instead of `document.querySelector('...')`.

Fixed fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/v8jrpnu2/21/

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the help.
Looks like some browsers havent loaded the image at the point i was adding to the canvas then? Im new to using JS for anything more than some basic handlers as you can probably tell.

Comment: Actually none browser should have. The loading of an image is asynchronous and should be made only after whole synchronous operations have been executed.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution gig :

```
                fabric.Image.fromURL(imageurl, function(oImg) {
                        oImg.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'
                        oImg.setWidth(wantedwidth); // additional
                        oImg.setHeight(wantedheight); // additional
                        oImg.set('left', 0).set('top',0), // additional
                        yourcanvas.add(oImg);
                        yourcanvas.renderAll()
                        yourcanvas.setActiveObject(oImg) // if you want to set the image active

                        });
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isnt the right solution - the image must load from an input not a url.

Answer (score 0):

```
function readURLForSticker(input) {
  TypeBelettering = "sticker";
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var imgs = new Image();
    imgs.onload = function () {
      originalImageHeightPX = this.height;
      originalImageWidthPX = this.width;
      imageHeightMM = originalImageHeightPX * 0.2645833333;
      imageWidthMM = originalImageWidthPX * 0.2645833333;


    };
    imgs.onerror = function () {
      alert("not a valid file: " + file.type);
    };
    urlLogo = _URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0]);
    imgs.src = urlLogo;
    reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
      imgs.src = e.target.result;

      stickerImage = new fabric.Image(imgs);
      canvas.add(stickerImage);
      canvas.centerObject(stickerImage);
      canvas.setActiveObject(stickerImage);
      canvas.renderAll();
          }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    alert("Als u een afbeelding wilt uploaden kan het zijn dat deze verborgen staat achter een tekst of eerder geplaatst ontwerp. U ziet wel een selectieveld van de afbeelding. Sleep deze een beetje en uw afbeelding wordt zichtbaar.");
  }

}
```

Comment: Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).